# How do I know if a cash loading / cash replenishment operation is done

Tags: xfs, cen-xfs

I am trying to develop a cash level monitoring application for ATMs.

I monitor the cash counters of ATM using CEN-XFS APIs.

The WFS_INF_CDM_CASH_UNIT_INFO command provides me the current cash level, but how do I know if counters are cleared and replenishment or a cash add is done ?

There is no specific event defined to indicate the same? Should I look for zero value in the counter to interpret the same as "clear counters"?

Comment: @Gabe Thorns: Could you help me with this ?

Comment: No, there aren't specific event. You should need to look at the data received to check if the countes have been cleared.